# Adding embdeded webpage to a tableview?

Tags: iphone, three20

I want to embed a webpage so it displays on this pasge

[image]
Under the Item, I would like to embed a web page so it displays as that page has live updates in HTML.

Could this be done?

Thanks

This is the code for the Table View as I'm using Three20

```
[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item1" URL:@"tt://countrylauncher"],
[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item2" URL:@"http://www.link1.org"],
[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item3" URL:@"http://link2.com"],
[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item4" URL:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lalalala/"],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `UIWebview as the`tableView`'s footer view.

Answer (score 0):

as coneybeare wrote you can set a section footer or create a custom cell. Then you can create your view in IB or create it programmatically just like you need it. (There are some tutorials around the web how to create a custom cell)

Comment: why someone downvote my answer? it is a possible solution. There is no "the only one"-answer. think again about for what down-votes are used!

Comment: If you are unsure about three20's capabilities, then why comment on them? A passerby might conclude that it is not possible from what you wrote, and it is possible. If you edit this line, I will remove the downvote

Comment: ok fixed, I just wanted to say that there maybe a possibility but I don't know how therefore I wrote that I don't know if its possible. upvoted yours ;)